# Matching two character list in R

Tags: r, list, string-matching

I have two character lists the first one is A

```
> mode(A)
[1] "character"
> length(A)
[1] 300
> dim(A)
[1] 150   2
```

the A is something like this

```
> head(A)
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] "000001" "601166"
[2,] "000027" "600582"
[3,] "000027" "600783"
[4,] "000027" "601088"
[5,] "000166" "000728"
[6,] "000333" "600519"
```

The second list is B which has 1000 elements

```
> length(B)
[1] 1000
> dim(B)
NULL
```

also each element of B has the below characteristics

```
> mode(B[[1]])
[1] "character"
> length(B[[1]])
[1] 300
> dim(B[[1]])
[1] 150   2
```

the `B[[1]]` is

```
> head(B[[1]])
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] "000001" "601818"
[2,] "000027" "600362"
[3,] "000027" "600827"
[4,] "000166" "601099"
[5,] "000333" "002304"
[6,] "000333" "601318"
```

I want to count of the frequency of the pairs of A's rows such as

```
"000001" "601166"
```

in each element of `B` such as

```
B[[1]]
```

I tried this code but couldn't get the result

```
Match<-list()
for(i in 1:1000){Match[[i]]<-match(as.data.frame(t(A)),as.data.frame(t(B[[i]])), nomatch=0)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for it, I just need to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the code.
The correct code is

```
M<-list()
for (i in 1:1000) {M[[i]]<-match(as.data.frame(t(A), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),as.data.frame(t(B[[i]]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), nomatch=0)}
```

any other suggestion to improve it will be appreciated.